# Non-simple property used in a cardinality restriction HermiT

Tags: java, reasoner, hermit

I am trying to reasoning my ontology in Java using HermiT but it results an error like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-simple property 'InverseOf(owl:topObjectProperty)' or its inverse appears in the cardinality restriction 'ObjectMaxCardinality(1 InverseOf(owl:topObjectProperty) owl:Thing)'.
```

i am new to reasoning in Java. what does it mean?

Comment: it's "reasoning in OWL" not Java ... and the error is exactly what the message says, you can't use non simple properties in max card. restrictions. that's it. read this and learn: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Global_Restrictions_on_Axioms_in_OWL_2_DL

Answer (score 0):

Try and uncheck the 'functional' property characteristics if you haven't explicitly set a cardinality constraint on that property.